# Azure timer triggered function ".past_due" returns false

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, timer, azure-functions

I'm writing my first, timer-triggered Functions and I'm having problems configuring them to run on their own. For explanation let's focus on just one.

The functions logs as run successfully but thanks to logging I identified that every time function is run "myTimer.past_due" returns "false" and function logic does not start.

How should I set it up so it would return "true" reliably?

How should i set it up so it would runvia "test-code" form portal?

What do i not get here? Is there some other timer that has to be matched?

I even went through and "turned it off and on again" by settig up new functions app and storage account in Azure to be sure i haven't broken up some settings on my way to this point.

Rationale: This one is ETL function that connects to third-party platform via API and inserts required data into azure SQL database. I would like it to run at 1 am each day. For starting function script I used the one provided via Microsoft DOC page, slightly modified, from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python

Here is mine "**init**.py":

```
import datetime
import logging

import azure.functions as func

from Toggl_Data_Procurement_Function import toggl_script


def main(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    logging.info(f"myTimer.past_due: {myTimer.past_due}")
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('Function %s, started by timer trigger, started running at %s', func.Context.function_name, utc_timestamp)
        toggl_script.TogglDataProcurementScript(root_directory=str(func.Context.function_directory)).run()

        utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    logging.info('Function %s, started by timer trigger finished running at %s', func.Context.function_name, utc_timestamp)
```

Here is my function.json - for debbugging I've set it up to run every 15 mins:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */15 * * * *",
      "useMonitor": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my local.settings.json. I edited out the storage account & instrumentation keys but they are the ones copied from appropriate app keys from platform:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~3",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "secret_key_2",
    "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING": "InstrumentationKey=secret_key_2;IngestionEndpoint=https://centralus-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account_name;AccountKey=secret_key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property `past_due` represents whether your timer trigger function be invoked in time. If your timer trigger function be invoked in time(works fine), it will be "false". Only when the timer trigger function be invoked later than scheduled, the `past_due` will be "true". You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python).

[image]

So you can't put the code under `if myTimer.past_due:`, you should write the code like below screenshot:

[image]

For your question of `How should i set it up so it would runvia "test-code" form portal?`. The timer trigger function should be executed according to the cron expression automatically. We should not run it manually on portal.

Comment: How much delay would make `mytimer.past_due` True?